# Google Maps API: Getting the trains at a train station?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation, google-places-api

I can use the Google Maps API in the following way to fetch set of train stations near a location:

```
    var request = {
        location : new google.maps.LatLng( 40.7829, 73.9654) ,
        radius : 500,
        type : [ "subway_station"]
    };
    var callback = function( results, status )
    {
        if( status === 'OK')
        {
            console.log( results );
        }
        else
            console.log("Unable to get nearby places at this time...");
    };

    var placeService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService( map );
    placeService.nearbySearch( request, callback );
```

Which returns records such as thefollowing:

```
{
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" :  40.7829,
               "lng" : -73.9654
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.7106958302915,
                  "lng" : -73.81892516970849
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.7079978697085,
                  "lng" : -73.8216231302915
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "3d01401185776e41c01a4c211dca4d49319343f9",
         "name" : "Briarwood - Van Wyck Blvd",
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 2826,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/101580679594295106213/photos\"\u003eJay Kindell\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "raw_reference" : {
                  "fife_url" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipPfK--UgtYinCZOMzuBhDlXg-567SVObqpV8OU=k"
               },
               "width" : 2474
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJL_WID79gwokR1C9hMstDeUU",
         "rating" : 3.5,
         "reference" : "CmRRAAAA8187TUFA1CrDZaHYUihPHfW3XNfBdXOyVng3cWkaOLGw2b2LEfweAqYj09PnRb0BPmSyp8wgeKkbG-RfD8uC6fA9KzZv_TOsvJWLiyj-K52gSuDCYg83RyqBR1QReO8AEhCx7aYumeiOv00Zlw_B4xc-GhR3OTWRrHo6sC2XeMQWrolrIFGszg",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [
            "subway_station",
            "transit_station",
            "point_of_interest",
            "establishment"
         ],
         "vicinity" : "&, Queens Boulevard & Main Street, New York"
      },
```

Even though the API provides me with all the nearby train stations, it doesn't give me which trains are at each of those stations. For instance, above record for Briarwood subway station has E and F trains, but the record doesn't have this information. Is there a way to get this information ? I can see this information on Google Maps:

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a feature request for Place details. You can file it in Google  [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188872&template=789309).

Comment: It looks like similar feature request already exists for bus stops, you can extend it by subway stops info: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35827961